# Query DynamoDB with GSI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

This is the table format I have load into AWS DynamoDB table where "uid" is a partition key and "followers" is a GSI created with "followers-index" name.

```
uid       | followers | followings |
-------------------------------------
adjeomax  | 2094      | 74         |
```

I want to query the table, for example "uid"s where "followers" are greater than 1000. How can I do that with Python. Below is the script I used for that, but give error.

```
response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('followers').gt(1000),
    IndexName="followers-index"
)
items = response['Items']
```

error I get:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query key condition not supported
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

GSI works like a new set of Primary Key (PK). In DynamoDB, a PK can consist of a Partition Key and a Sort Key. Partition Key can only be queried using exact match, while Sort Key can be queried using ranges, like `gt`.

In your example, seems `followers` is the Partition Key in your GSI. Therefore, you cannot query it using comparison operators like `gt`.

If your table is small, you can work around this problem by having all your rows in a single partition and having `followers` as the SortKey of your GSI. For example, create a dummy column `app` having the same value for all rows:

```
GSI
app (Partition)   | followers (SortKey)    | uid
--------------------------------------------------
Metagram          | 100                    | 101
Metagram          | 99                     | 102
Metagram          | 99                     | 103
```

This way, you will be able to query `followers >= 100`.

Otherwise, a better method would be to determine your table access pattern and find a more meaningful Partition for your GSI.